# Ruby on Rails - Multisite - Custom Locale YML files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale, multisite

We are running a white label type site where several websites run from one codebase.

I would like to have the locales files with all of the site text loaded from a different folder based on a parameter.

Lets say we have these two sites:

- `site1@example.com (site1)`
- `site2@example.com (site2)`

We are reading the host and determining the `brand_name` from our site model.

So in the locales files I would like to load them from the correct folder, i.e.

- `config/locales/site1/**/*.yml`
- `config/locales/site2/**/*.yml`

I can not seem to do this dynamically. I can make the change in the `config/application.rb` file manually and it works fine. However I want to be able to determine which set of locale files to load in my `application_controller.rb`

Am I able to set the the path of the locale files or is this too late?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

*application.rb*

`config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', request.host, *.{rb,yml}').to_s]`

This will only load locale files in a folder with the domain name.  If a user goes to site2.com it will load files in config/locales/site2.com/*.yml